# Compressing time series by removing repeated samples

Tags: python, performance, numpy, compression, pandas

I work on a project with time series data. So there are samples (\$y\$), and each sample has a timestamp (\$x\$). The data will be visualized, but often there are time series which contain samples that do not change over several timestamps. In a visualization (a \$y(x)\$ plot) those repeated samples can be removed, since the visualization will just show a horizontal line. (For example, if a constant value 3.14 is sampled 1 million times in one second, the plot would have the same visual appearance as if the value had been sampled just twice in that period.) I wrote an algorithm that removes those repeated samples in the order to reduce the amount of data and speed up visualization. My algorithm works, but I know that it can be done better.

Here is the algorithm (in the file compress_2D_signal.py):

```
def compress_2D_signal(x, y):
    end = len(x)
    end_1 = len(x) - 1
    x1 = []
    y1 = []

    x1append = x1.append
    y1append = y1.append

    for ind, elements in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
        if ind == end or ind >= end_1 or y[ind - 1] != y[ind] or y[ind + 1]     != y[ind] or ind == 0:
        x1append(elements[0])
        y1append(elements[1])
    return x1, y1
```

and here are the tests:

```
from unittest import TestCase
import time
from compress_2D_signal import compress_2D_signal


class Test2DSignal(TestCase):
    def test_store_sample_array_one_signal_parameter_returns_same_when_each_sample_different(self):
        x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        y = [0, 1, 2, 3]
        x1, y1 = compress_2D_signal(x, y)
        self.assertEqual(x, x1)
        self.assertEqual(y, y1)

    def test_store_sample_array_one_signal_parameter(self):
        x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        y = [0, 2, 2, 2, 0]
        x1, y1 = compress_2D_signal(x, y)
        self.assertEqual([1, 2, 4, 5], x1)
        self.assertEqual([0, 2, 2, 0], y1)

    def test_store_sample_array_one_signal_parameter_2(self):
        x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        y = [0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
        x1, y1 = compress_2D_signal(x, y)
        self.assertEqual([1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9], x1)
        self.assertEqual([0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1], y1)

    def test_time_self(self):
        length = int(1e6)
        x = range(length)
        y = range(length)
        start = time.time()
        compress_2D_signal(x, y)
        stop = time.time()
        print('Time elapsed for %s points : %s this are %s points/second' % (length, stop - start, length / (stop - start)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to keep points where the value for \$y\$ is different from either the preceding or succeeding value. So in NumPy you can write:

```
import numpy as np

def compress_2D_signal(x, y):
    """Compress signal y(x) by omitting repeated values for y.

    Takes a signal y(x) as two array-likes x and y. Returns the
    compressed signal y1(x1) as the tuple x1, y1, where y1 contains
    the first and last values of y, and values of y that are different
    from the preceeding or succeeding value, and x1 contains the
    corresponding values from x.

    """
    x, y = np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y)
    keep = np.empty_like(x, dtype=bool)
    if len(x) > 0:
        keep[0] = keep[-1] = True
        keep[1:-1] = (y[1:-1] != y[:-2]) | (y[1:-1] != y[2:])
    return x[keep], y[keep]
```

Notes on this code:

1. This returns NumPy arrays (not Python lists), so you'll need to revise your test cases to use [`numpy.testing.assert_array_equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_array_equal.html) instead of [`unittest.TestCase.assertEqual`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual).
2. If you pass it Python lists, then much of the runtime will be in the [`numpy.asarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html) call (converting the input to NumPy arrays) and not in the compression code. So for a fair test I think it makes sense to update `test_time_self` so that it calls [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) instead of `range`.

   With this change, I find that the revised code is about 30 times faster than the original code.

A couple of other review points:

1. There's no docstring for `compress_2D_signal`. It's hard to use and maintain code when there's no documentation.
2. The test case code is very repetitive — it would be simpler to loop over a list of cases, like this:

   ```
   from numpy.testing import assert_array_equal

   class Test2DSignal(TestCase):
       _CASES = [
           # x, y, x1, y1
           ([1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3],
            [1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3]),
           ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 2, 2, 2, 0],
            [1, 2, 4, 5], [0, 2, 2, 0]),
           ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
            [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9], [0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1]),
       ]

       def test_2D_signal(self):
           for x, y, x1_expected, y1_expected in self._CASES:
               x1_found, y1_found = compress_2D_signal(x, y)
               assert_array_equal(x1_expected, x1_found)
               assert_array_equal(y1_expected, y1_found)
   ```

   This makes it easier to add new cases. In particular, I would add tests for edge cases such as empty and single-element inputs, like this:

   ```
       _CASES = [
           # x, y, x1, y1
           ([], [], [], []),
           ([1], [1], [1], [1]),
           ([1, 2], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 1]),
           ([1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1], [1, 3], [1, 1]),
           # etc.
   ```